# How to keep "My billing address is same as above" UNTicked by default?

Tags: civicontribute, templates, billingblock

"My billing address is same as above" field by default is checked. I would like to keep it "UNTicked" by default. How can I do it?

I have tried to modify the template file in civicrm/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.tpl and change `<input type="checkbox" id="billingcheckbox" value="0">` value to 1, 2. But that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone give me a hint how to do it from the template file please?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out

Comment: How did you solve it?  You could submit your own answer and in a couple days mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further down (halfway) to the Billingblock.tpl change the following value from true to false

```
// detect if billing checkbox should default to checked
          var checked = false;
```

Comment: Did you modify the core file billingblock.tpl or create a custom one?  If you did not create a custom one (or even better use a .extra.tpl) then your changes will be lost when you upgrade next.

Comment: I have placed a modified  billingblock.tpl in custom template directory.